# Generating single cucumber.json using Karate Framework

Tags: karate

I am using parallel execution in my Karate Tests. I was trying to generate a single cucumber.json file inside `target` folder. 
With the current set up, I have different json and xml files in the surefire-reports folder. Is there a way I could generate a single json file with the feature results ?

```
@CucumberOptions( format={"json:target/cucumber.json"})
public class TestParallel {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
        KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, karateOutputPath);
        generateReport(karateOutputPath);
        assertTrue("there are scenario failures", stats.getFailCount() == 0);
    }
```

Any help or pointers will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you never need to. [All reporting solutions](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report) are able to handle multiple JSON files.

Is there any specific reason why you want a single JSON ?

Comment: yes, we wanted to update a downstream system with the test results and is easier to process with a single json file. Any utility you have in mind which I can leverage to combine the different json files ?

Comment: @Saurabh - thanks for the update. No one else has requested this, so your best bet would be to try and work out a solution on your own. If you really get stuck, you can open a feature request, or better still - contribute a solution :P

Comment: @Saurabh - you might get some ideas from the code of the cucumber-reporting project, it aggregates the JSON: https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting